# ANgular 7 : How to format a date using ng-model?

Tags: angular7

I'm using .net core api with angular7.

I have a problem to convert dateTime to Date with ngModel

```
 <input class="form-control" name="dateT"
 [(ngModel)]="exp.dateTo  |date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" #dateT="ngModel" type="date"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead if two-way binding.Use one way and have a event handler to update User input.

```
<input class="form-control" name="dateT" (ngModelChange)="updatedate($event)" [ngModel]="exp.dateTo |date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" #dateT="ngModel" type="date"/>
```

In your ts file add updatedate to update the ngmodel

```
 updatedate(event) {

        this.exp.dateTo = new Date(event);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but when i updte the input value i got this error : ERROR TypeError: _co.updatedate is not a function

Comment: did you add "updatedate(event) " as function in your ts file?If not please add it

Comment: I have updated my answer which would resolve your issue.please mark the answer if it has worked for you.Thanks